# avahi-daemon runs with wrong hostname

Tags: hostname, yocto, avahi

I have a problem on one device where the `avahi-daemon` is running with the wrong hostname and it is messing up my system.

The hostname is `ABC-100001` but when I check the process list it shows that

```
avahi       9243 20.7  0.0   6964  5408 ?        Ss   02:39   0:01 avahi-daemon: running [ABC-100002.local]
```

Using `hostnamectl set-hostname localhost` and restarting the `avahi-daemon` changes the process to:

```
avahi       9601 11.0  0.0   6652  5148 ?        Ss   02:40   0:00 avahi-daemon: running [linux.local]
```

Changing it back `hostnamectl set-hostname ABC-100001` and restarting the daemon again shows it running as `ABC-100002`.

I have searched high and low but can not figure out where the `avahi-daemon` gets it hostname from.